# Should I separate typography section from the HTML hierarchy?

Tags: html, css, typography

Is it a good practice to make a separate section of CSS rules applying only for typography? or should they be part of the HTML hierarchy flow?

The question is mostly from readability and maintainability point of view.

Comment: What is "HTML hierarchy flow"?

Comment: ordering the CSS according to the order of the HTML - "header" "content" "footer" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, it's best practice to keep things modular. Put your CSS in its own file(s), and, if you have a lot of stylings (very common), I'd say you can have a `typography.css` to make the rules very clear. HTML is supposed to be meaningful (as the purpose of HTML5 is to go back to this idea), and this should extend past the use of tags to the placement of files and readability of your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is of cource no correct answer to this question, but in my experience: both.

I feel that I gain a lot from a good css reset, and they do tend to handle some typography. 
But aside from that I have yet to gain from a separate style-sheet for typography only.